# Python Selenium cannot find input

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to target the login input fields on this [Website](https://www.genedx.com/signin/).
So far I have tried using, ID, Name. Add a wait until present or wait until clickable but no luck.
Using chropath to try and get an xmlpath does not work on this element either for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, there is an iframe so you need to switch to iframe first.

try below **code** :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.genedx.com/signin/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='catapultCookie']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#biopeople-login-registration iframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "loginEmail"))).send_keys('user name here')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```